# Parse org-mode clocktable CSVs into time sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, csv

For my student job, I have been logging work times with the `org-mode` in emacs for quite some time. Now since I can only work from remote, I figured it would be nice to automatically use the entries from the .org files into readily-formatted entries. I am doing this because the job requires me to write an Excel sheet with the hours worked each month in a specific format:

- For each day, there is one entry
- Each entry features the date, start and ending time, pause in minutes, and hours worked.

With the help of the Emacs package [`org-clock-csv`](https://github.com/atheriel/org-clock-csv) I was able to generate CSV output containing start and end times including dates. I wrote a Python script to parse these into the desired format, and I feel there is a lot of room for improvement.

The input looks like this (`testoutput.csv`):

```
organization,,,2020-04-03 10:49,2020-04-03 13:19,,,
some stuff,,,2020-04-03 10:39,2020-04-03 10:49,,,
more stuff,,,2020-04-02 12:25,2020-04-02 12:25,,,
some stuff,,,2020-04-02 09:43,2020-04-02 09:47,,,
other stuff,,,2020-04-02 09:35,2020-04-02 09:43,,,
organization,,,2020-03-27 14:00,2020-03-27 14:28,,,
Orga,,,2020-03-27 09:10,2020-03-27 09:42,,,
Orga,,,2020-03-23 09:13,2020-03-23 09:25,,,
Orga,,,2020-03-22 09:56,2020-03-22 10:03,,,
```

There are several things the code needs to do: summarize entries for each day, parse the times and dates, and compute total time worked as well as pause times. Pause times are the result of the difference of (latest end - earliest start) and the actual total time worked.

The result should look like this (`testoutput_parsed.csv`, actual output of my script):

```
date,start,stop,pause (minutes),total (hours)
02.04.,09:35,12:25,158,00:12
03.04.,10:39,13:19,0,02:40
22.03.,09:56,10:03,0,00:07
23.03.,09:13,09:25,0,00:12
27.03.,09:10,14:28,258,01:00
```

As far as I can tell, the output is correct. However, I am looking for comments on code quality in terms of structure, complying with conventions and such.

Here is the actual code:

```
import datetime
from operator import itemgetter
import csv


def read_timestamps_from_csv(csv_filename, delim=','):
    with open(csv_filename, 'r') as file:
        times_list = []
        for line in file:

            # skip header
            if 'task' in line:
                continue

            try:
                start_str, stop_str = line.split(delim)[3:5]
                start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
                stop_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(stop_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
                times_list.append([start_time, stop_time])
            except:
                print(f'unable to parse this line: {line}')
        return times_list


def summarize_timestamps(timestamp_pairs):
    summary_stamps = []

    for stamp_pair in timestamp_pairs:

        # check if date is already in summary_stamps
        if date_is_present(stamp_pair[0], summary_stamps):

            # if so, add time and change end time
            date_idx = get_date_index(stamp_pair[0], summary_stamps)

            if summary_stamps[date_idx]['date'] == stamp_pair[0].date():

                new_start = min(stamp_pair[0].time(), summary_stamps[date_idx]['start'])    
                new_stop = max(stamp_pair[1].time(), summary_stamps[date_idx]['stop'])

                summary_stamps[date_idx]['start'] = new_start
                summary_stamps[date_idx]['stop'] = new_stop
                summary_stamps[date_idx]['total'] += stamp_pair[1] - stamp_pair[0]

        else:
            # if not, add a summary_stamp with start time, end time and time
            summary_stamps.append({'date':stamp_pair[0].date(),
                                   'start':stamp_pair[0].time(),
                                   'stop':stamp_pair[1].time(),
                                   'total':stamp_pair[1] - stamp_pair[0]
            })

    # add break field
    for s, sumst in enumerate(summary_stamps):
        stop_start_diff = datetime.datetime.combine(sumst['date'], sumst['stop']) - datetime.datetime.combine(sumst['date'], sumst['start'])
        pause_time = stop_start_diff - sumst['total']
        summary_stamps[s]['pause_min'], _ = divmod(pause_time.seconds, 60)

    return summary_stamps


def date_is_present(timestamp, summary_stamps):
    if summary_stamps == []:
        return False

    for summary_stamp in summary_stamps:
        if summary_stamp['date'] == timestamp.date():
                return True

    # if no date is present:
    return False


def get_date_index(timestamp, summary_stamps):
    for s, summary_stamp in enumerate(summary_stamps):
        if summary_stamp['date'] == timestamp.date():
                return s


def parse_summary_stamps_to_entries(summary_stamps):

    entry_list = [[] for i in range(len(summary_stamps))]
    for s, sumst in enumerate(summary_stamps):

        total_hours, rem = divmod(sumst['total'].seconds, 3600)
        total_minutes, _ = divmod(rem, 60)

        entry_list[s] = [
            sumst['date'].strftime('%d.%m.'),
            sumst['start'].strftime('%H:%M'),
            sumst['stop'].strftime('%H:%M'),
            sumst['pause_min'],
            f'{total_hours:02}:{total_minutes:02}'
        ]

    return entry_list


def sort_entries_by_date(entry_list):
    return sorted(entry_list, key=itemgetter(0))


def write_times_to_csv(sorted_entries, fname_out, delim=','):
    with open(fname_out, mode='w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=delim)
        for entry in sorted_entries:
            writer.writerow(entry)

    print(f'wrote csv file: {fname_out}')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    fname_in = 'testoutput.csv'
    fname_out = 'testoutput_parsed.csv'
    timestamp_pairs = read_timestamps_from_csv(fname_in)
    summary_stamps =summarize_timestamps(timestamp_pairs)

    entry_list = parse_summary_stamps_to_entries(summary_stamps)


    sorted_entries = sort_entries_by_date(entry_list)

    header = ['date', 'start', 'stop', 'pause (minutes)', 'total (hours)']
    #print(header)
    #for entry in sorted_entries:
    #    print(entry)
    sorted_entries = [header, *sorted_entries]

    write_times_to_csv(sorted_entries, fname_out)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pathlib

Rather than accepting `csv_filename` as a string, accept it as a `Path`. Then

```
with open(csv_filename, 'r') as file:
```

becomes

```
with csv_filename.open() as file:
```

### Generator

Turn `read_timestamps_from_csv` into a generator that yields 2-tuples:

```
from datetime import datetime
# ...
DATE_FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

def read_timestamps_from_csv(csv_filename: Path, delim: str=',') -> Iterable[Tuple[datetime, datetime]]:
    with csv_filename.open() as file:
        for line in file:

            # skip header
            if 'task' in line:
                continue

            try:
                start_str, stop_str = line.split(delim)[3:5]
                start_time = datetime.strptime(start_str, DATE_FMT)
                stop_time = datetime.strptime(stop_str, DATE_FMT)
                yield start_time, stop_time
            except Exception:
                print(f'Unable to parse this line: "{line}"')
```

Also note:

- Factor out a formatting constant
- Importing of the `datetime` symbol
- Never `except`; at least catch an `Exception` if not a more narrow type
- Some type hints

### `summarize_timestamps` / `date_is_present`

This:

```
for summary_stamp in summary_stamps:
    if summary_stamp['date'] == timestamp.date():
            return True
```

is a search in linear time - O(n) complexity, which is slow. To reduce this to constant time, or O(1), use a `set` of dates and the `in` operator; or alternately maintain a dictionary whose keys are the dates.

The dictionary approach would simplify your code in `summarize_timestamps`. You have two loops. The first loop would still need to keep a dictionary since you're going back and mutating entries before being able to yield them.

Then, your last loop can further mutate to add the break field and yield there.

This can be more simplified if - instead of using a dictionary - you use an actual class, with attribute of `date`, `start`, `stop` and `total`. Also, this loop:

```
for stamp_pair in timestamp_pairs:
```

should immediately unpack that pair, i.e.

```
for start, stop in timestamp_pairs:
```

### Time math

```
    summary_stamps[s]['pause_min'], _ = divmod(pause_time.seconds, 60)
```

is a red flag.

You're throwing out the second return value from `divmod`, so why call it at all? If you still wanted to do your own math, just use integer division - `//`. However, you should nearly never be doing your own time math.

This is one of the many things that C# does better out-of-the-box than Python, but anyway: reading [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds), the recommended method (without bringing in a third-party lib) is:

```
summary_stamps[s]['pause_min'] = pause_time // timedelta(minutes=1)
```

The same goes for

```
    total_hours, rem = divmod(sumst['total'].seconds, 3600)
    total_minutes, _ = divmod(rem, 60)
```

### Redundant `if`

This:

```
if summary_stamps == []:
    return False
```

should get deleted, because if that list is empty, the iteration will execute zero times and the return will be the same.

However, the whole function can be replaced with

```
td = timestamp.date()
return any(stamp['date'] == td for stamp in summary_stamps)
```

### Sorting

Have you tried

```
return sorted(entry_list, key=itemgetter(0))
```

without the `key`? The default behaviour is to sort on the first item of a tuple.

Comment: Thank you very much, your advice is very helpful to me! How exactly can `summarize_timestamps` or `summary_stamps` be turned into a generator? The difference to me is that for each function call, there may be several inputs necessary to generate a single output. This would require multiple runs of the outer for loop. Did I miss something?

Comment: Also, the type hints for `read_timestamps_from_csv` seem to require me to import `Iterable` and `Tuple`. Is it generally recommended to add imports for type hints?

Comment: _Is it generally recommended to add imports for type hints?_ - Using type hints, in general, is a good idea. There are some differing opinions on how this is done. Some prefer string-style type hints (i.e. `csv_filename: 'Path'`) and others bare symbols as I have shown. Some prefer that the import from `typing` be done in an unconditional manner, and others prefer to wrap their typing imports in an `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING` clause. Some prefer qualified type references like `typing.Tuple` and others just `Tuple`.

Comment: You can experiment a little, but my preference is - bare, not string; unconditional; and unqualified.

Comment: As for `summary_stamps` - I've made an edit.